How to parse markdown in a JSON file
I'm creating an app that fetches data from an API and prints it, pretty straightforward. The problem is that some data comes what which some kind of markdown for italic, like this:
[
{
"t": "a {it}dog{/it} who needs a loving home"
}
]

I'm using using EJS templating language for the front end. This is how I would fetch the previous data:
<% if(sense[0][1].dt[1]){ 
const example = sense[0][1].dt[1][1][0].t; %>
<div class="col-12 sense-example-wrapper">
<p class="sense-example"><%= example %></p>
</div>
<% } %>

So the previous sentence in the JSON data is the variable <%= example %>
I'm trying to parse that {it}dog{/it} (and all the occurrences of that markdown) into italic in CSS, but I don't know how to do that. I've been googling it but I found nothing.
Thanks in advance.
P.S.: sorry for the poor explanation, but I'm still kinda new to programming.

Well all you need to do is to replace the correct strings into <i>text</i> = text
So:
const example = sense[0][1].dt[1][1][0].t; 
const formatted = example.replace(/{it}/ig, "<i>").replace(/{\/it}/ig, "</i>");

And
<p class="sense-example"><%= formatted %></p>

Or better yet, without escaping the <> tags,
<p class="sense-example"><%- formatted %></p>


Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm. While I understand the replace method, I'm not an expert on regex, so that's why I didn't go that way. Can you explain to me what the ig means in the regex?
Thanks!

i = ignore case, g = globally (that is, replace all)

@JuanManuelLinares ig are flags for the regex, I'd say you could compare it to when you add arguments to a command e.g. the -i in ssh -i  .... Here is a list of all the flags.
